# How to get git with Netbeans running on MacOS X?

Tags: git, netbeans, osx-snow-leopard, netbeans-plugins

I'm quite sure I've seen git in the Available Plugins section of Netbeans but right now it's not there. Is it just temporarily missing or am I doing wrong? All three standard repositories are activated. I'm running Netbeans 7.0.1 on Snow Leopard.

Comment: With Matt's help I found a direct download for manual install: http://plugins.netbeans.org/download/plugin/39785 - this solves the problem, but leaves the question why it's not on the Update Center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing for me too. I don't think it's been certified for the 7.0.1 release yet (only 7.0 is mentioned [here](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/37577/git-versioning-system-support))

Edit: It's appeared now. I installed github for mac ([here](http://mac.github.com/)), then Xcode from the mac app store, one or both of which installed the previously missing git binaries. NetBeans must have been hiding the git stuff whilst it was impossible to do any of it.

Comment: I had a 7.0 install before where it was also missing. After your comment I even tried a fresh install of 7.0 which was unsuccessful too.
But with the help of your link I could download the package and install it manually. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can upgrade/check an early version of [NetBeans7.1](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeans_71), you would get a more complete Git support, including push/pull operations.
See ["Git Support Finalized"](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB71#Git_Support_Finalized).

> Complete Git Version Control support is now part of the standard distribution and available right after installation of the IDE.

Meaning: no issue with trying to find it elsewhere ;)

Comment: Daniel, thanks for sharing. So I look forward to the release of 7.1.